# Error in generating a new component using angular cli in asp.net core spas

Tags: angular, angular-cli, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to add a new component in `Asp.Net Core 2.0 SPAs` using `angular-cli`. I added dev dependencies in the project's root folder using

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

angular-cli version

> Angular CLI: 1.7.1;
>   Node: 8.9.4;
>   OS: win32 x64

But when i write `ng g c ComponentName` this error occurs

> C:\Users\USERNAME\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\node_modules\@angular\cli\upgrade\version.js:12
>   const { bold, red, yellow } = chalk_1.default;
>          ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot destructure property `bold` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
>       at Object. (C:\Users\USERNAME\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\node_modules\@angular\cli\upgrade\version.js:12:39)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\USERNAME\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\build.js:4:19)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)

I saw [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8202) solution but none of them worked for me. How to resolve this issue?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you tried deleting `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` and the `node_modules` and reinstalling them?

Comment: There are no such folders by that names ...

Comment: Just delete lock.json files and node_modules as suggested by @ArjunPanicker and re-install node_modules.

Comment: Try taking your cli version back to 1.5.x

Comment: Go to ur project's root folder and delete the files named - `package-lock.json`, `yarn.lock`(if exists) and delete the folder called `node_modules`. Then do `npm install` again in the root folder of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this.

`npm uninstall @angular/cli`
`npm install @angular/cli@1.5.x`

Then try again generating your component

**Another Solution**

As i can see that your `animation` module is on `Angular 4`

If above method does not work change the version of the angular/cli to `1.4.10`

`npm uninstall @angular/cli`
`npm install @angular/cli@1.4.10`

Hope it helps!